# Using an object in another class

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

Here my example for my problem:

```
    namespace test
    {
         public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

    private Data theData= new Data();
    private Handler theHandler = new Handler(theData);

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    } 
    ......

    }

    class Handler
    {

        Data theData;
        public Handler(Data theDa)
        {
          theData = theDa;
        }

        //some funktions which are using theData

    }

    class Data
    {
        public Data()
        {

        }
        public string a;
        public string b;
    }

    }
```

I have a window class, with a instance of a class to do somethink (Handler) and a class to store data (Data).

I think the way I showed is a little bit quick and dirty. Can someone tell me how I'm able to use theData in my Handler class without using the constructor?

Comment: I don't see a reason why you shouldn't do what you are doing? Looks good, unless there is some other detail I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this 100% correct (besides having all the classes in one file!)

For `Handler` to act on an instance of `Data` it must be given it. There are other ways besides in the constructor (assigning a property, or a parameter to its methods) but if a given instance of `Handler` should only act on one instance of `Data` then your model is just fine.

The only other issue is that you have public fields in `Data`, which is considered bad practice; you should use properties instead (with PascalCase names).

The only other alternative I can think of is to have `Handler` instantiate `Data` if `MainWindow` doesn't care about the `Data` reference.